# DataGridView selected row index

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Why is the dgView.CurrentCell.RowIndex always 0?  I need to know which row and column a user is trying to edit.  column 1 can only be edited if it is a new row.  column 4 can be edited only if it is not a new row.  No other columns can be edited.
I need to be able to add a new row.
I've tried .CellBeginEdit with e as DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs

And no, I don't want to bind my data to the SQL table.  I need to make sure the user knows they are changing the data when they save it.

I've tried with CellMouseClick and CellMouseLeeave with disastrous results.  I found these two and thought I had them working but testing proves that not to be the case.
My code (some of which is redundant as I'm still trying to understand what events I should be working with):

```
Private Sub dgTools_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dgTools.CellBeginEdit
    Dim i As Integer
    With dgTools
        i = .CurrentCell.RowIndex
        Select Case e.ColumnIndex
            Case 1
                If .CurrentCell.RowIndex < .NewRowIndex Then
                    Dim msg As Object, hdr As Object
                    msg = "You may not edit the tool ID"
                    hdr = "Edit Error"
                    MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, hdr)
                End If
            Case 4
                originalValue = .CurrentCell.Value
        End Select
        .EndEdit()
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub dgTools_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgTools.CellEndEdit
    Dim dtCheck As New DataTable
    Dim hdr As Object, msg As Object

    With dgTools
        .EndEdit()
        Select Case e.ColumnIndex
            Case 1
                Select Case originalValue
                    Case ""
                        .CurrentCell.Value = UCase(.CurrentCell.Value)
                        dtCheck = GetDataTable("GetTool_x_BrochsteinsID", "@BrochsteinsID", .CurrentCell.Value)
                        ' Brochsteins ID is not a valid ID
                        If dtCheck.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                            hdr = "Invalid Brochsteins ID"
                            msg = "Entry is not a valid Brochsteins ID." & vbCrLf & "Please enter a valid ID."
                            MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, hdr)
                            .Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                        ' Check that Brochsteins ID is not already assigned to a toolbox
                        If dtCheck.Rows(0)("Toolstatus") > 1 Then
                            hdr = "Illegal Brochsteins ID Assignment"
                            msg = dtCheck.Rows(0)("BrochsteinsID") & " is already assigned to " & dtCheck.Rows(0)("ToolboxDesc") & vbCrLf &
                                      "Please enter a different Brochsteins ID or Return this ID to the Tool Room first."
                            MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, hdr)
                            .Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                        .CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = dtCheck.Rows(0)("ToolId")
                        .CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = dtCheck.Rows(0)("ModelDesc").ToString
                        .CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value = dtCheck.Rows(0)("CategoryDesc").ToString
                        .CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value = dtCheck.Rows(0)("AssignedNote").ToString
                    Case Else
                        If originalValue <> .CurrentCell.Value Then
                            hdr = "Edit Brochsteins ID"
                            msg = "You may not edit a Brochsteins ID." & vbCrLf & "You may only Delete and/or Add a new Brochsteins ID."
                            MsgBox(msg, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, hdr)
                            .CurrentCell.Value = originalValue
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                End Select
        End Select
        Dim Note As String
        If Not IsDBNull(.CurrentRow.Cells("AssignedNote").Value) Then Note = .CurrentRow.Cells("AssignedNote").Value Else Note = ""
        UpdateTool_Toolbox(.CurrentRow.Cells("ToolID").Value, cboToolbox.SelectedValue, Note)
        If dtCheck IsNot Nothing Then dtCheck.Dispose()
        dgTools.EndEdit()
        QueryTable("Tools")
        QueryTable("Standard")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using .currentrow?  The datagridviewcellcaneleventargs has properties to identify the row and columns

Comment: the honest answer is because I didn't know any better.  This is my first "real" solution and I'm still really learning how to program in VB.NET.  SQL and vba I'm pretty good.  VB.NET, not so much and a work in progress.  I've been doing some more testing and now see that DataGridViewCellEventArgs also provides the info I'm looking for.  I'm also reworking the way the program steps through the select case statement.  I think I can make that a lot better as well.  I'll post my final solution here when I get it working so this at least has an answer for other newbies who stumble upon it.

Comment: The whole reason for checking the row index in column 1 is because I don't want a user to change an ID, only add them.  If I make the column read only I can't add a new ID.  Finally I hit on the idea of making the cell read only as I add data from my datatable retrieved from my SQL server.  BINGO.  That resolves the problem.